# Convert variable integer to percentage in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert the variable integer data into percentage in creating a bar chart. However it seems it is not working. What have I missed?

```cs
string x1 = var_Product_name;
int y1 = Tools.ConvertToInt_02(var_Amount);

// This is the code I used to convert the var_Amount to get the percentage and display as data series in bar graph together with the var_Amount value however this isn't working

int y2 = Tools.ConvertToInt_02(var_Amount)/ 100.ToString("0.00%"); 

BarChartData_Product_Records_Data_View.Add(new BarChartSourceData_Product_Records_Data_View(x1, y1, y2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `var_Amount` is in the range 0..100, so even

100/100

results in 1, while smaller values, e.g.

25/100

results in 0 because `y2` is an integer. To fix it, change `y2` to a type that supports decimal portions such as `float`, `double`, or `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the `Tools.ConvertToInt_02(var_Amount)` returns an integer value this line will not compile: you have `int` value on before `/` and `string` value after `/`.

You should see:

> error CS0019: Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int'
> and 'string'

If assume that the `var_Amount` is double value that you want to format to the percentage, use the following method:

```
string specifier = "P";            
var result = (var_Amount / 100).ToString(specifier, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

For example, if `var_Amount` has value `12.3456` the `result` will be `12.35 %`, when the current decimal point character for the current culture is `.`.

For additional information see documentation: [Double.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)